# Turbulent Boundary Layer Thickness as Velocity Increases

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm attempting to find the highest free stream velocity over a flat plat before a sensor placed 'delta' away from it experiences turbulent flow. When I plot this in Matlab it seems that the turbulent boundary layer thickness decreases with velocity. This seems pretty counter intuitive to me, am I thinking of this in the wrong way? Or am I making a silly coding error?

These are the governing equations

$$\begin{align}
\delta &\approx \dfrac{0.37x}{Re_x^{1/5}} \\
Re_x &= \dfrac{\rho u_0x}{\mu}
\end{align}$$
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer_thickness)

**EDIT** : Do not include any 'clear' or 'delete' code when posting, because many people do not want their workspace cleared.

*Matlab Code*

```
% clc
% clear all
rho = 1025;   % density of water
mu = 0.00108; % dynamic viscosity
x = 65e-3;    % distance from leading plate edge
U = linspace(0,10); % Free Stream Velocity
Re = (rho*U *x)/mu;
turb_lay = (0.382*x)./(Re).^0.2
lam_lay = (5*x)./(Re).^.5
plot(U,lam_lay,U,lam_lay2,U,turb_lay)
xlabel('Velocity (m/s)')
ylabel('Boundary Layer Height (m)')
legend('Laminar Boundary', 'Turbulent Boundary')
```

Comment: Why would you think the boundary layer height increases with velocity? You even have the expression for $\delta/x \sim 1/U^{1/5}$. Hence, the boundary layer height decreases by $1/U^{1/5}$.

Comment: Poor intuition I suppose. I guess the quicker the flow is moving the less opportunity it has to spread outward from the plate and deform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the velocity increases, the fluid will not be able to form a cohesive boundary layer because the fluid particles will not have the needed residence time near the boundary layer to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your setup is OK. I would recommend reading a few documents or texts which discuss boundary layer behavior.

I found possibly useful monographs via Google.
[This PDF](http://www.mne.psu.edu/cimbala/me320web_Spring_2015/pdf/Flat_plate_turbulent_BL.pdf) includes some tables such as 
[image: Table10.4] .

The following is a PowerPoint lecture which may also help

[GoogleLink](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwikmsCSnqvRAhUDNSYKHRqLDZcQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.nd.edu%2F~msen%2FTeaching%2FIntHT%2FSlides%2F07A%2520-%2520Chapter%25207%2520-%2520Sec%25207.1-7.3%2CApp%2520F%2520-%2520Black.ppt&usg=AFQjCNHVRXdiJvniCPMhTytKD_jkmT3v6g&sig2=gEo0gSDeDhOXuV-50dq2WQ)